# Django: How can I access previous results via navigation bar?

Tags: django, session-variables

I implemented a Django website to search my database. My navigation bar has the following permanent tags: Search, Results, Article, About, Contact. After I submit the term on the Search-site,
the Result-site opens and shows a list of all possible hits from the database. From there, I can click on a link to navigate to the Article-site to read the article. However, when I leave the Result-site to another site and want to go back later by clicking on the Result-tag, I want to see the previous results again. But it won’t reopen my previous results because I neither send a request to the corresponding search methods nor can I tell the tag which dynamic url to open (`/search/term`).

How can I revisit my previous results? Can I somehow keep the result stored on this side until I start another search via the Search-site? I saved the search term as session variable. Can I send a request containing a session variable by clicking on a tag in my navigation bar?

I do not want to use a back-button because it should be possible to go back to the Result-site independent from where you are right now on the website.

Can you please help me?

#### views.py

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = S
    template_name = 'app/index.html'

class ResultsView(DetailView):
    model = S
    template_name = 'app/results.html'
    context_object_name = 'results'

def search(request):
    term = request.GET['term'] #search term
    request.session['query'] = term
    results = S.objects.filter(name=term)
    list_of_results = [model_to_dict(aresult) for aresult in results]

    return render(request, 'app/results.html', {'list_of_results':list_of_results})
```

#### base.html

```
<header class="naviBar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            {% block index %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'app:index' %}">Search</a>
            </li>
            {% endblock %}  
            {% block results %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'app:results' %}">Result</a>
            </li>
            {% endblock %}
            {% block contact %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'app:contact' %}">Contact</a>
            </li>
            {% endblock %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `Generic detail view ResultsView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`
That is my Error, so I tried to add a pk value to the url in my base.html and I also tried a slug. Both didn't work.

Comment: Please post your view code.

Comment: thanks for the nice edit and sorry for the wrong quotes, they were a copy paste mistake

Comment: so your `ResultsView` is supposed to display a single `S` object?  that's what it means to use the `DetailView` base class

Comment: @Anentropic , yes thats right, but if click on another tag in my navibar and then i want to see it again by clicking on the Result-tag, I get an error insted of my S object, which I had before. I would like the results to be there until I start a new search. How can I do that?

Comment: `DetailView` expects the primary key of the `S` object to be supplied in the url... you need to modify the view so that it gets the pk from session instead